# VSCode の 「Markdown Preview Enhanced」の html 変換をコマンドラインから実行したい

Tags: vscode, markdown

PlantUML のダイアグラム付きの資料を作成する際、 VSCode の Markdown Preview Enhanced が便利なので使っています。

このプラグインは、プレビューを右クリックすることで表示されるメニューから `HTML` を選択していくことで、 html ファイルとしてプレビューを export することができます。

今、例えばこの資料を github 管理などする際に、 CI で html ファイルを自動で生成できると便利です。

## 質問

VSCode の [Markdown Preview Enhanced](https://github.com/shd101wyy/vscode-markdown-preview-enhanced) のプラグインでマークダウンの資料を作成しているとき、それの html 変換をコマンドラインから実行したいです。これは、可能でしょうか?

Comment: このIssue [Command-line export #181](https://github.com/shd101wyy/markdown-preview-enhanced/issues/181) でライブラリを別プロジェクト [shd101wyy/mume](https://github.com/shd101wyy/mume) として切り出したようなので、Issueの最後の方にあるスクリプトを流用するか自分で書くことでコマンドラインツールを作成出来る感じです。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@kunif さんに紹介いただいた、 [mume のライブラリ](https://github.com/shd101wyy/mume)を用いることで、やりたいことが実現できました。
その際に利用したスクリプト(ほぼ README のコピペで、かつ html ではなく pdf 変換をしましたが)を貼っておきます。

```js
#!/usr/bin/env node

// md-to-pdf.mjs

// es6
import * as mume from "@shd101wyy/mume"

async function main() {
  // const configPath = path.resolve(os.tmpdir(), ".mume");
  //
  // // if no configPath is specified, the default is "~/.config/mume"
  // // but only if the old location (~/.mume) does not exist
  // await mume.init(configPath);

  const engine = new mume.MarkdownEngine({
    filePath: process.argv[2],
    config: {
      // configPath: configPath,
      previewTheme: "github-light.css",
      // revealjsTheme: "white.css"
      codeBlockTheme: "default.css",
      printBackground: true,
      enableScriptExecution: true, // <= for running code chunks
    },
  });

  // // open in browser
  // await engine.openInBrowser({ runAllCodeChunks: true });
  //
  // // html export
  // await engine.htmlExport({ offline: false, runAllCodeChunks: true });
  //

  // chrome (puppeteer) export
  await engine.chromeExport({ fileType: "pdf", runAllCodeChunks: true }); // fileType = 'pdf'|'png'|'jpeg'

  // // prince export
  // await engine.princeExport({ runAllCodeChunks: true });

  // // ebook export
  // await engine.eBookExport({ fileType: "epub" }); // fileType = 'epub'|'pdf'|'mobi'|'html'
  //
  // // pandoc export
  // await engine.pandocExport({ runAllCodeChunks: true });
  //
  // // markdown(gfm) export
  // await engine.markdownExport({ runAllCodeChunks: true });

  return process.exit();
}

main();
```

利用方法:

```
$ path/to/md-to-pdf.mjs hogehoge.md
# => hogehoge.pdf が出力される
```